# ros2 repo for rhel not available for aarch64

Tags: ros2

I am using rhel 9.3 in a virtual machine on a Mac (aarch64), following the instructions to install ROS2 it seems there is no repo available for my architecture (only x86_64). See: http://packages.ros.org/ros2/rhel/9.

Is ROS2 supported on aarch64?

Will this repo be updated and when? Or is the an alternative rpm solution I can use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The best resource to understand which platforms are supported is REP-2000 [[1](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#iron-irwini-may-2023-november-2024)]. For ROS 2 Humble/Iron/Rolling on arm64, only Ubuntu is Tier 1, there isn't any tier specified for RHEL, so you will have to build from source.